# Append dict to list without duplicate python django

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I have this object `data_listmedia`:

```
print(data_listmedia) : 
[{'id': 6, 'withdegrey_id': 1, 'withsecondray_id': 2, 'nomberesteda': 400, 'nomberhodor': 30, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)}, {'id': 7, 'withdegrey_id': 2, 'withsecondray_id': 2, 'nomberesteda': 400, 'nomberhodor': 200, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)}, {'id': 8, 'withdegrey_id': 1, 'withsecondray_id': 2, 'nomberesteda': 200, 'nomberhodor': 120, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)}]
```

Now I want append this persontage dict to all dicts in this list so I use this loop:

First I declared

```
    mydict ={}
    data = []

    for l in data_listmedia:
        persontage = ((l["nomberhodor"] * 100) / l["nomberesteda"])
        mydict.update({"percontage": persontage})
        data.append(mydict)
        mydict.update(l)
```

but when finish the loop it appends the last dict in list

```
print(data)


[{'percontage': 60.0, 'id': 8, 'withdegrey_id': 1, 'withsecondray_id': 2, 'nomberesteda': 200, 'nomberhodor': 120, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)}, {'percontage': 60.0, 'id': 8, 'withdegrey_id': 1, 'withsecondray_id': 2, 'nomberesteda': 200, 'nomberhodor': 120, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)}, {'percontage': 60.0, 'id': 8, 'withdegrey_id': 1, 'withsecondray_id': 2, 'nomberesteda': 200, 'nomberhodor': 120, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)}]
```

Why when I use `data.append(mydict)` does it duplicate the last dict in the all list?

but when I use

```
print(persontage)
```

inside the loop
the value comes true

```
7.5
50.0
60.0
```

How can I append dict to list without duplicate?

Comment: You don't create a new dictionary, you only update the *same* dictionary each time. The list `data` contains multiple references to the *same* dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same dict reference in the list, so basically each elements points to the same dict in memory. To fix this at high level do:

```
new_dict = dict(my_dict)
```

And work with "new_dict".